# does "sluggish" have a negative connotation?

Tags: word-choice, collocation

Context:
The Processing Speed for situations requiring immediate attention is **sluggish**

I'd like to know if this sounds acceptable in a neuropsychological report, or if there's a more suitable word.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

zac, you might consider the word **[depressed](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sluggish&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#q=define+depressed&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)**: reduce the level or strength of activity in (something, esp. an economic or biological system).

> On the first 2 days after caffeine discontinuance, [depression](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1182710-overview) of locomotor ....

or, possibly better, impaired, lowered or even *lag*

> Significance and sign of transmission as a function of the [**lag**](http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v16/n10/fig_tab/nn.3509_F6.html) between the posterior probability time series associated with vertical category representation in prefrontal and parietal cortex.
>
> The DLPFC response systematically [lagged](http://bmb.oxfordjournals.org/content/65/1/49.full) behind the VLPFC response, consistent with a hierarchical model

Comment: Thank you once more, Susan. I think "lowered" is the best option here, since I've been using impaired to translate another word, with a slightly different connotation. Although "depressed" is acceptable, the word is too easily associated to psychological depression in this particular context, and it indeed appears with that sense in the same text. So I'd rather avoid this confusion. "Lag" is a word with which I don't have much familiarity, particularly as an adjective. It sounds a bit strange. Anyway, that was really helpful and useful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The short and simple word here would be *slow*.

Comment: I guess that would be really too simple for the present context. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd find something more neutral, such as *prolonged*, or *protracted* to use in a neuropsychological report.  "Markedly prolonged" is often used in medical writing and may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here, the word *sluggish* suggests 'slow,' but at the same time, there's no referent. Slow compared to what?

I think a better option would be to use a word like *diminished*, with specific reference to some other process, or processing state.

Also, why capitalize "Processing Speed"?

Comment: It is considered slow in relation to normative patterns, so to speak. There's no particular reason to capitalize the phrase except that it is like that in the original text (also with no apparent reason) and as a translator, I don't think I should change that.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Sorry I didn't realize you were translating, so my advice isn't really relevant.

Comment: No problem. Actually, I didn't mention it was a translation at first, and you couldn't know. Thanks for your input.